# GAE HR commit/visibility + timestamp

Tags: google-app-engine, visibility, commit

GAE HR is one step towards scalability, separating commit and visibility, but one step back in usability. This separation creates a problem (the "eventual consistency"?) that kills its use in some  application designs. Usually, I commit inside a http request and redirect to another page that shows the results, but I have to make a small delay (many milliseconds) to try to get the changes of that commit. This is the easiest workaround I find for this, not a fix. Unfortunately, I do not have a guarantee that I got the changes of that commit. Due to multiple computing synchronism paradigm, I think it is not possible to know how long the change updates will take, what could take milliseconds, minutes or even days (in an improbable case).

I was wondering I could "fix" this by using timestamps, what are easy pass to another request in a query string or to store in a session memcache variable. If I have the timestamp of my last commit, any later query to the database could use this timestamp to check if the retrieved data was committed after that timestamp, if not, it retries the query again and again. This way I have the guarantee of the correct visibility ("strong consistency"?), even if takes a long time. It can eventually read data committed by another user/process after that timestamp, what I do not consider a problem. Is this approach correct?

I can implement this with a timestamp field in every table, but a lib would be better (built in timestamp fields, automatic tuning of polling time, internal cache session timestamp of last commit, and maybe some low level database callback instead of the polling). Is there a third party lib like this? I know ORM libs that use GAE low level database APIs, but I have no idea how to start something like that.

Answer (score 1):

For strong consistency in GAE datastore - use ancestor queries.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Ancestor_queries

Comment: I just want a minimal change in the application to achieve the correct visibility, at least in some queries. If the concept is correct, I would implement a lib like that. It is easier to use one timestamp (eventually hidden behind a lib) than to redesign the database.

Comment: By any chance, a workaround for this is to create a dummy table and make it parent of my table? Does it guarantee any queries in my table? Even after insertions? This problem is pretty hard to spot, so any advice is appreciated.